# How to split a string into an array in jQuery when there is only one element in the string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, that takes a string and splits it into an array:

```
nodes = $("#" + model_id + "-" + node_class + "--" + "title").data("nodes").split(",")
```

When there is only one element in the string (no commas), the variable "nodes" does not become an array, but a regular variable. So when I try to iterate over each element in "nodes", nothing happens if the original string only contains one element. If it has several elements, everything is OK.

```
$.each(nodes, function (id, node_id) {
  if ($("#" + model_id + "-" + node_class + "-" + node_id + "-" + "chkbx").is(":checked")) {
    counter ++
  }
})
```

I have tried to declare "nodes" as an array, but when I assign the splitted string, it's all the same. Since I use a "split" to assign values I don't think I can use "push" to append values to the array.

I have tried to put square brackets everywhere, I think, i.e. like this:

```
[nodes] = $("#" + model_id + "-" + node_class + "--" + "title").data("nodes").split(",")
```

... but that didn't help.

Is there any solutions to this, except from checking if "nodes" is an array or not, and then write different code to handle both options?

Comment: Could you post some kind of demo that reproduces your problem (or at least explains/demonstrates it) at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar? There might be an alternative approach to the problem that I can't see from just looking at your jQuery.

Comment: Split should always return an array for just this reason. I second the comment from @DavidThomas that a complete example would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When there is only one element in the string (no commas), the variable "nodes" does not become an array, but a regular variable.

A) Variables referring to arrays *are* regular variables. B) That's not how `split` works. `split` **always** returns an array. If the delimiter isn't present in the string, the resulting array is one element in length. ([Live proof](http://jsbin.com/ehucop)) So as long as `data` returns a string, `nodes` will be set to an array. Note, though, that `data` does **not** always return a string, and so `data("nodes").split(",")` may fail with the error that `split` is not a function, because `data` can return `null` or an object as well as `string`. If you **know** it will always be a string because of your application logic, that's fine, but if so `nodes` will always be an array, which is why I mention it.

Re your comment below: Iteration works just fine on single-element arrays: http://jsbin.com/ehucop/2

I suspect you need to look at the JavaScript console in your browser, I bet you'll find an error occurring which is preventing your iteration code from running at all.

Comment: OK. Thank's for explaining this. My problem is still the same. If the string has one element, the iteration doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JohanHovda: The problem is in code you haven't quoted, iteration works just fine on single-element arrays: http://jsbin.com/ehucop/2

Comment: @JohanHovda I suppose it could depend on some wrong name for the check boxes you are looping on...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thank's a lot for the extended explanation. To turn the data into a string I replaced '.data("nodes")' with '.attr("data-nodes")', and now it works.

Comment: @JohanHovda: Glad you sorted it out, I expect that's because `attr` always returns a string (well, except for `tabindex` and such). I guess my paranoia about using `data` to access `data-*` attributes is justified (I always use `attr` to get them, because `data` is too overloaded with other functionality). Although in a simple test, it seems like `data` returns strings as well: http://jsbin.com/uyoyed Your page must be more complex. :-)